# how to conditionally transform div to and from a state on multiple presses of same button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
$(".inside").css("transform","translateX(0px)")
});
```

hOW DO I ABLE TO MAKE THE JS CODE TRANSLATE ON CLICK BACK AND FORTH?
    if($(document).click("button")){
    $(".inside").css("transform","translateX(400px)");
    }
    });

```
</script>
<style>
#cont{
background:#98bf21;
height:400px;
width:400px;
}
.inside{
    background:#09C;
height:400px;
width:400px;
position:absolute;
overflow:hidden;
transform:translateX(-500px);
transition:1s;
}


</style>
<body>
<button>Button</button>
<div id="cont" >
<div class="inside"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Using "Caps lock" is not appropriate for this system.

Comment: sorry ill keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked = false

    $("button").click(function(){
        if (clicked)
            $(".inside").css("transform","translateX(-500px)");
        else 
            $(".inside").css("transform","translateX(0px)");

          clicked = !clicked;
    });
});
```

Comment: let just say i want to do the same thing again but with the different button while the when you click the other button the first div should overflow hidden and the second container translate in front

Comment: You just need two `click` listeners, one for each button. In one of them you set `$(".inside").css("transform","translateX(-500px)");` and in the other `$(".inside").css("transform","translateX(0px)");`

Comment: $("button").click(function(){
        if (clicked)
           $(.inside1").css("transform","translateX(0px)");
        if(clicked) 
            $(".inside2").css("transform","translateX(-1200px)");
     if(clicked)
   $(".inside3").css("transform","translateX(-1200px)");
        if(clicked)
      $(".inside4").css("transform","translateX(-1200px)"); 
  else
      $(".inside1").css("transform","translateX(-1200px)");

          clicked = !clicked;
    });

Comment: is this how am i suppose to do it